# Basic XSLT's when-test conditional tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I was trying to test my XSLT against sample XML file.
However, the output would only contain an empty  tag.

I believe it fails at `<when test="self::text()">`
I thought if it was a text, it would print the value.

Please please tell me what went wrong.

---

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt2.xslt"?>

<library>
 <book><page>30</page></book>
 <book>fun</book>
</library>
```

---

XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="t">
            <xsl:with-param name="b" select="."></xsl:with-param>       
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="t">
        <xsl:param name="b"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$b/*|$b/text()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::text()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"></xsl:value-of>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Your solution doesn't look good for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your template is called on the root node `/` white space before and after the document element is ignored and does not contribute a text node so the root node just has two children, the element node library and the process instruction xml-stylesheet. so

```
$b/*
```

selects the element library and

```
$b/text()
```

selects nothing

and so the `xsl:for-each` just does one-iteration which then returns false for the test `self::text()"`

Answer (score 0):

Looping in XSLT is best done implicitly by applying templates. Your thinking seems to be a bit too much influenced by procedural programming languages.
The below for instance, loops over all subnodes and extracts the text values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|text()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="text()">
                <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no"/>
            </xsl:when>
       </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on the XML supplied, this gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>30fun</result>
```